# Unable to build project with gradle 4.1: "unknown element * found"

Tags: android, gradle

After updating to Gradle 4.1 I'm unable to build my project (all works fine with previous releases).

Basically it doesn't recognize AndroidManifest tags anymore and gives me errors in the generated manifest in `/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug`.

Here's the build log:

```
/home/paolorotolo/dev/exp/***/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
    Error:(30) unknown element <action> found
    Error:(32) unknown element <category> found
    Error:(33) unknown element <category> found
    Error:/home/paolorotolo/dev/exp/core/***/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:30 unknown element <action> found
    Error:/home/paolorotolo/dev/exp/core/***/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:33 unknown element <category> found
    Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
    Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
    Error:Execution failed for task ':***:processDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt
    Information:BUILD FAILED in 6s
```

Comment: it seems like it isn't updated completely, invalidate and restart the studio and resync the project

Comment: Already tried. Also re-imported the project but nothing.

Comment: create a new empty project and check if it runs fine or not? if yes then check cofig diff in your project and if not then move to last stable version of gradle

Comment: yep, new projects are fine, I'm using same config of this one. That's why I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: compare the gradle file settings of both projects and clean the project.

Comment: Solved going back to gradle 4.0.2. Seems an issue of latest release, I hope they will fix it soon :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in new gradle release *(gradle-4.1-rc-2)*.

To solve add in your `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-2-all.zip
```

Comment: This somehow doesn't help me, I am on Android Studio 3, and once I do this, I get the following error: "Error:(10, 0) Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.1. Current version is 4.1-rc-2.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings."

Comment: same exact issue for me.

Comment: I'm getting this too, I swear each major android studio release, something breaks and you're just left to wonder why :(

Answer (score 1):

For now using gradle 4.1, or even 4.2 on your gradle wrapper will break builds that have  dependencies

I solved this issue by taking back my gradle classpath depency back to gradle 2.3.3

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your AndroidManifest.xml,make sure every element like 'action' or 'category' is in right position.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the similar issue recently, The way I solved is by invalidating the cache. You can do that in android studio-> File-> Invalidate cache/ Restart.

After that it stop showing me those ActivityFeed error.