# Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 - unknown element <action> found in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having this issue with Android Studio 3.0 beta 2 where it basically does not resolve anything inside my `Manifest.xml`

This is how the LogCat looks like when trying to run the app:

```
> Error:(60) unknown element <action> found
Error:(66) unknown element <action> found
Error:(71) unknown element <action> found
Error:(76) unknown element <action> found
Error:(81) unknown element <action> found
Error:(86) unknown element <action> found
Error:(91) unknown element <action> found
Error:(96) unknown element <action> found
Error:/Users/daniele/Developer/Android Projects/Chords2/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:60 unknown element <action> found
Error:/Users/daniele/Developer/Android Projects/Chords2/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:71 unknown element <action> found
Error:/Users/daniele/Developer/Android Projects/Chords2/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:81 unknown element <action> found
Error:/Users/daniele/Developer/Android Projects/Chords2/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:91 unknown element <action> found
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
```

This is how my app `build.gradle` looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        ######_key {
            keyAlias '######'
            keyPassword '######'
            storeFile file('#######.jks')
            storePassword '######'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "######"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 16
        versionName "2.1"
        signingConfig ######
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.heinrichreimersoftware:material-intro:1.6.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have ### out the data regarding my signing key.
To me it looks alright.

I also tried cleaning, rebuilding, resyncing the gradle file, Still no luck though.

This is a logcat screenshot. Maybe it's more readable

[image: error]

Based on MikeM suggestion I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506536/6427630) and changed in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-2-all.zip
```

The error is still there though

Comment: please share Manifest file code?

Comment: There's for sure nothing wrong in the manifest. It's compiling fine in android studio 2

Comment: Thanks Mike, will try this out

Comment: @MikeM. I've changed from `rc1` to `rc2` still the error is there.

Comment: I had forgotten about this question, until I just came across it searching my history. I'm not sure if you ever solved this, but your problem is misplaced tags in the manifest. The older tools would just ignore them, but the newer ones throw that error. `<action>` elements must be inside `<intent-filter>` elements. Since they were just being ignored previously, you can simply delete the ones on the lines specified in those error messages.

Comment: @MikeM. Why is this question been marked as duplicate it's been asked in August and the "duplicate" one was asked in October, shouldn't the other one be marked as duplicate?

Comment: The purpose of marking questions as duplicates is to link to the correct answers. The dates don't matter, though the phrasing in that banner is slightly misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the gradle version or downgrading it didn't resolved the issue

I have got the similar issue recently, The way I solved is by invalidating the cache. You can do that in android studio-> File-> Invalidate cache/ Restart.

After that it stop showing me those ActivityFeed error.

Answer (score 0):

For me what helped was to modify the classpath in dependencies of the build.gradle file of the project.

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
```