# Updated to Android studio 3.0 and gradle version 4.1 : unknown element <action> in debug/manifest.xml. really don't know what to do?

Tags: android, gradle

```
Error:(30) unknown element <action> found
Error:(32) unknown element <category> found
Error:(33) unknown element <category> found
```

I read developers documentation but couldn't help
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

this is a part of manifest file (couldn't send all of them ) :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application

    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> ...
```

Comment: Do you have those elements in the wrong spots? It checks for that, now.

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373053/unable-to-build-project-with-gradle-4-1-unknown-element-found

Comment: @MikeM. don't know what the problem is , it worked with previous version fine

Comment: Yeah, it used to ignore tags in the wrong spots. Now it doesn't. You've apparently got three misplaced.

Comment: @SachinAggarwal , I tried all answers but did not work

Comment: @tahaDev Please upload the manifest file

Comment: Those `<action>`s do not go there. `<action>` and `<category>` elements go inside `<intent-filter>`s, which go inside component elements, inside `<application>`.

Comment: Check the line 30-33

Comment: where should I put that <action> ? will u please explain more!

Comment: Those particular actions would go inside the `<intent-filter>` in a `<receiver>`. If you already have them there, then just delete those you've shown in that snippet, as they were never doing anything anyway.

Comment: I try it . but still don't get it . I will read about it . thx mike

Comment: No problem. The linked duplicate has a link in the answer that describes the manifest structure: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct. You can have a look through that for the specifics, but, really, if your app was working as intended before the upgrade, you probably just need to delete the lines it's complaining about, because, as mentioned, they were just be ignored before anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear project and reload it. This helps most of the times.

Comment: I did it but didn't help

Comment: Then it's probably one of the many android studio errors. :(

Comment: one said it is solved in new grade version but it is not in my AS updates list